# Why do we travel on an elliptical path towards Mars?

Tags: mars, spacecraft

A typical rocket path to Mars is shown below:

[image]

Why can’t we just cut diagonally through instead of travelling over a long elliptical path? Sort of like this:

[image]

Comment: Pretty certain we have a canonical question on this but I can't find it. In short, what you are proposing is like a handbrake turn in space - not possible (unless we find a way to neutralise momentum) We are travelling along the blue line; using thrust to push us away from that blue line, thus leading to an ellipse, is the only possible approach. And we need to use more thrust to then make us meet Mars' orbit.

Comment: Because it isn't the movies, maybe?

Comment: There's nothing physically impossible about the second trajectory; it's just that no spacecraft humanity has ever built, or will build in the near future, is capable of flying it. The delta-v requirements are too darn high.

Comment: It boils down to how both the Earth and Mars are moving at high speed in orbits around the Sun, and any vaguely efficient path between them will be an orbit that connects them while being close to parallel to both of them. If we had ultra-high-delta-V thermonuclear rockets like in The Expanse, we could do what you suggest, but that requires operating at the very upper limits of nuclear reactions.

Comment: Note that if you use Earth as the reference, the path travelled is actually quite close to your drawing, the spacecraft just goes from Earth towards the orbit of Mars. The shape seen on the first drawing is just because it’s taken in a reference frame where Earth moves... though in some cases even in an Earth reference frame the path is a bit more complex than just a straight line to Mars.

Comment: There are no straight line orbits possible within the solar systems.